# Conditionally Navigate To The Bookmarks In The PowerBI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence

I have created login functionality in the PowerBI report as shown [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/adding-password-box-power-bi-report-wyn-hopkins).

There is one button to login and if the credentials are correct, Then the button will move the user to the dashboard.

From the dashboard, I have created two bookmarks "Admin" & "Other" to separate the view of the both type of users.

There are some shapes & buttons which "Admin" users can see but not the "Other" users & Vice versa. So, I have created two bookmarks as described above.

[image]

[image]

I am drilling one flag measurement 'Measurement_IsAdmin' into the dashboard. This flag stores a boolean value if the credentials were of "Admin" user.

I want to navigate to the bookmarks based on condition of 'Measurement_IsAdmin' flag. If this flag has true value, Then the login button should show the "Admin" bookmark view to the user. Otherwise, "Other" view.

Note that, I don't want to create the separate reports or page for "Admin" & "Other" types of users.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you share your pbix file ?